# How to switch to a different interface programmatically?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my storyboard for my watch app I have a few different interface controllers. I want to switch to a different interface programmatically. For example, when a timer has ended.

I am looking for something similar to how you would switch view controllers in normal iOS apps:

```
UIStoryboard *createS = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *createV = [createS instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Scoreboard"];
[self presentViewController:createV animated:NO completion:nil];
```

How could I do this for watch apps with interface controllers? I am making my app in Objective-C but an answer for Swift might be useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the code.

```
- (void)presentControllerWithName:(NSString *)name context:(id)context;
```

name = Interface Identifier